# JQUERY causes security errors in Win 8.1 apps

Tags: jquery, winjs

So I decided to include JQ in my W8.1 project. MS claims JQ works, but I'm getting the following security error:

> Unable to add dynamic content ''. A script attempted to inject dynamic
>   content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be
>   unsafe. For example, using the innerHTML property to add script or
>   malformed HTML will generate this exception. Use the toStaticHTML
>   method to filter dynamic content, or explicitly create elements and
>   attributes with a method such as createElement.  For more information,
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=247104.

That's only by linking JQ min 2.1.1 - not actually using it or doing anything.
Oh and by linking I mean locally not CDN.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Is there maybe a special W8 version?
Thank you.

Comment: "Fixed" it by downgrading to JQ 2.0.2.

Comment: In that case you should check if there is an entry about this on the [bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/) and create one if there isn't.

Comment: Jquery 2 was the first Windows Store ready version http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/04/01/windows-store-app-support-in-jquery-version-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case same error was occurred when I was try to enter HTML content dynamically and if content have some differ attribute than this type of error occurred. I just declare a variable for HTML value and put  that value like: window.toStaticHTML(value)..  That works for me. Evan error message also state that use toStaticHTML method..

All the best..!!